# "An error occurred" when trying to configure update steps of Case entity in all workflows

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

I have a technical issue with workflows in CRM 2015.

I get an error when clicking the "configure" link/button on the update step of case/incident in WF (workflows). It occurs on all update steps on case, on all WF. Update steps on all other entities work fine, even in WF that runs on case.

The error message is “An error has occurred.” It leaves an error event in windows event log. Here are some highlights from the event:

1. Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred.
2. Request URL: [http://hostname/orgname/SFA/Workflow/entityform.aspx?appSolutionId={B3E6D7A7-84B2-4BB3-A381-BD9D5E9C7916}&entityFullName=incident&entityname=incident&mode=1&primaryentity=incident&stepId=UpdateStep13&workflowId=e2b5b3e5-9d5d-4c96-90f6-55d3c4a971a3](http://hostname/orgname/SFA/Workflow/entityform.aspx?appSolutionId=%7BB3E6D7A7-84B2-4BB3-A381-BD9D5E9C7916%7D&entityFullName=incident&entityname=incident&mode=1&primaryentity=incident&stepId=UpdateStep13&workflowId=e2b5b3e5-9d5d-4c96-90f6-55d3c4a971a3)
3. Exception type: UriFormatException
4. Exception message: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
   Note: I replaced the hostname and orgname parts of the URL.

I enabled tracing and looked at the trace log. Found no new information there, still the Invalid URI error. Since the system breaks when parsing the URI, the log is very short.

Clicking on the link in the event, or pasting it into the browser gives the same error. However, **it works when following the link when on the same machine (hostname).**

The most relevant article I could find by Googling is this: [Getting error on CRM 2011 Plugin: "Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508060/getting-error-on-crm-2011-plugin-invalid-uri-the-hostname-could-not-be-parsed)
The cause of the problem in the article was found to be related to two plugins executing on the same entity and message. I cannot find any other relevant articles.

There are no plugins involved in my case, but the problem occurred after updating a WFA (workflow activity) DLL with two new WFA. The two new WFA are being used in two WF, but both WF are deactivated. I tried removing both WFA calls from the WF, and unregistered both new WFA in PRT (Plugin Registration Tool), and updated the WFA DLL with the old DLL (not containing the two new WFA) in PRT. None of these things helped.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It works in other browsers than IE, but the customer only uses IE.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue with 2015 on Premise.  Suddenly I get a generic "an error has occurred" message when I try to set the properties in a Case update step, in a workflow.  And with a create case step, too.

The error occurs when I tried chrome, so not an IE issue.

I am not using any plug-ins at all, purely native CRM tools.  I had just finished adding a load of fields and auto-hide business rules to my case form, so wondered if that was the issue (a limit on fields perhaps?).

My fix was to deactivate that form and set another, more basic Case form, as active (just changing the active form order didn't work).  Now the update step works fine.  Switching back to the more complex form, the error reappears.

The error only occurs in the workflow designer.  There are no errors in the form designer, form preview or live view - so looks like a bug in the workflow designer.

Hope that does the (albeit tedious) trick for you!